# using qt with custom loop in python

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, python-3.x

I have been experimenting around with using QT in python3 and figured out how to make a simple .ui file and import it directly into a python program. However I have to use python QT app while I would like to have my own custom loop in order to be able to add things to it. So what I have now is:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.desktop = uic.loadUi('mytest.ui')
        self.desktop.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've played around a bit with PGU where I have been able to do this with what would be

```
while True:
    window.loop()
```

in the main which allows me to put in my own extra code that is unrelated to the GUI without dealing with multiple threads. However I have been unable find some equivalent to "loop" in qt and searching for "qt custom loop/update/blit python" hasn't found anything relevant besides suggestions to add a 0 second timer to my app and place extra code there which seems... inelegant to me. I would like to import a GUI into my app rather then building my app around a GUI.

Edit: Here is my updated code taking Phyatt's answer into account for anyone else looking for the same answer I was.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic

class TestApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi('mytest.ui')
        self.ui.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TestApp()
    app.processEvents()
    while True:
        app.processEvents()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using your own custom loop, the more common way to do that is to have a timer event scheduled on the Qt loop, or to launch another thread.

If you still really wanted to use your own loop, you need to manually call `QApplication.processEvents()` in your loop and it probably should work.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimerevent.html#details

```
MyWindow.start(100) # start the built in timer event for that QObject 10 times a second
```

And then in `MyWindow` put `def timerEvent` and it should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: app.processEvents() is what I was looking for. I knew about the timer but that just seems wrong to me for some reason. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Using timerEvent, lets you do all sorts of stuff, and it is how Qt works under the hood for most of its processing.  It feels wrong to a functional programmer because it doesn't look like a for loop.  But it has a lot of advantages with how you can do animations, poll the system, respond to user input, and even cross thread boundaries safely.  Give it a shot sometime when you are feeling bold.  It is a more "Qt way" of doing it and it lends itself to cleaner, less buggy code.

Comment: You're probably right, it just doesn't feel "pythonic" to me. As I said before, it makes more sense to me to import a GUI into my program rather then build a program around a GUI which seems to be the QT way of doing things. Of course since most of my attempts at working with GUI's are either very minimal or fail completely this way of thinking is undoubtedly part of my problem, which is why I'm experimenting with different GUI's right now.